# Assembly 8086: Swapping Parameters Values by Reference

Tags: assembly, stack, pass-by-reference, x86-16

in my program i'm trying to swap between 2 referenced values but it seems i have a problem in dereferencing the first parameter from the stack without using SI register.

Can please someone help me? Sorry for misknowladge, i am just a newbie.

```
jmp main

toSwap1     db 'a'
toSwap2     db 'b'

main:  


lea si,toSwap1
push si
lea si,toSwap2
push si
call swap

 mov ah,0
int 16
ret




swap proc
push bp                 
mov bp,sp

mov si,bp+4   ;second param address
mov ax,[si]   ;second param value


mov bx,[bp+6]   ;address of firstparam
mov dx,ds:[bx]   ;first param value


mov sp,bp 
pop bp    


retn 4 ;takes 2 parameters

swap endp
```

Comment: What you did was just load the two values, you forgot to write them back into memory. Not sure what your problem is with `si`.

Comment: @jester Currently my problem is dereferencing the value of the second parameter, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the code is fine except for missing brackets around `[bp+4]`. What you need is write back the result swapped, that is you are missing `mov [si], dx; mov [bx], ax`.

Comment: @Jester Actually the part of BP+4 works without the brackets  (ax stores the value of "toSwap2") and I think I understand your solution , thanks anyway and good night.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your comment, your solution actually works but can you please explain me  why      mov [SI],DX    changes the value of the second parameter if DX stores the address

Comment: It doesn't. You loaded the **value** into `DX`, `SI` has the address. The code does: `AX=*SI; DX=*BX; *SI=DX; *BX=AX;` Just loads the values and writes them back swapped.

Answer (score 0):

After `call swap` you need to somehow exit to the operating system, or else the CPU will proceed to re-execute your swap function, with catastrophic results.

Assuming a 16-bit memory model, and assuming that what you want to swap is ***bytes***, (judging by the `db 'a'` and `db 'b'`) what you want to do inside your `swap` function is something like this:

```
mov si,[bp+4]
mov di,[bp+6]
mov al,[si]
mov ah,[di]
mov [si],ah
mov [di],al
```

<sub>For future reference: " it seems i have a problem " is not an adequate description of a problem.  Try explaining a) precisely what you expected to see happening, and b) precisely what happens instead.</sub>

Comment: Well, I wrote "something like this".  You might need to tweak it a bit. For example, you appear to assume that your parameters are at bp+4 and bp+6, so I am using the same offsets, I do not remember off the top of my head whether these are the correct offsets.  But in any case, it is not magic, you are supposed to understand how it works.  I am giving you the right direction in which to proceed.

Comment: I think I figured what's the problem, see amendment.

Comment: And, one more amendment.  (Sorry about that.  It is late.  I better go to sleep.)

Comment: Your code swaps their stack location, my problem was dereference them and swap their values so their stack placement stays the same and their memory addresses as well

Comment: Yes, see last amendment (5 minutes ago)

Comment: Good night Mike and don't forget about me please :)